Visual Studio 2019 - how to display variable contents like Visual Studio 2010 did?
I have got 2 Versions of Visual Studio installed - 2010 and 2019. I was working with 2010 for years and I am really used to the behaviour of that app version.
Now in 2019 some string variable values are shown quite different compared to 2010:
This is 2019:

This is 2010:

How can I set up 2019 to display string variables in the same way 2010 did?
I prefer the "raw" mode as I can copy the values and paste it into regexr.com p.ex. for further analysis ...
I have checked settings and so on with no success

Additional Screenshot

All I want to achieve is to be able to debug the code in VS 2019 in the same way as it was in VS 2010. The string variable "content" should be formatted as the additional screenshot shows for VS 2010.
unfortunately I cannot upload the mentioned file ("HPa01AVAD") to provide a sample you could try at your end.

Click the small magnifying glass on the far right side of your red line box to view the complete value. Or you can share your string with us, but please note that when testing, please ensure that VS2010 and 2019 use the same value.

The problem I have ist not the length of the value ... it's that some special characters are "translated" in something like "vbNullChar" in 2019
My screenshots above show the same variable - once when the code is debugged in 2010 and once in 2019
